# Divisibility of the function $\,f(n)=2n^2-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let's consider the following arithmetic function:
$$f(n)=2n^2-1,\;\;\;\;\;\;n\in \mathbb N.$$
**Prove (or eventually disprove) that either $\,f(n)\,$ is prime or, otherwise, a natural $\,1\lt m\lt n\,$ exists s.t. $\,f(m)\,|\,f(n)$.**

Many thanks.

Comment: What about $f(1)=1$? Doesn’t this divide everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disprove: $n = 29, 32, 53, 55, 57, 60, 67,\dots$ are all counterexamples to the assertion.

E.g. for $n = 29$: $f(n) = 1681 = 41^2$.

If there exists $1 < m < n$ such that $f(m) \mid f(n)$, then necessarily $f(m) = 41$, and hence $m^2 = 21$, which is impossible.